# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in variable name[i]

Tags: python, syntax

ENVIRONMENT:
Windows 7
Python2.7
Eclipse SDK 3.7.2

Trying to follow a tutorial from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-HpXbhVuGo
I receive an error message:

============================= ERRORS =============================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 432, in **get_module_from_str
    mod = __import**(modname)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\workspace\assignment3\fileiotest.py", line 17
    print(bestStudent[i] + ‘ scored a ‘ + i)
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
ERROR: Module: fileiotest could not be imported (file: C:/Users/lenovo/workspace/assignment3/fileiotest.py).

.........................................................................................

```
#-*- coding: utf8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function


bestStudent = {}
f = open ("C:/Users/lenovo/workspace/assignment3/studentgrades.txt")
for line in f:
    name, grade = line.split()
    bestStudent[grade] = name

f.close()

bestStudentStr= "" 

for i in sorted(bestStudent.keys(), reverse=True):
    print bestStudent[i] + 'scored a ' + i
bestStudentStr += bestStudent[i] + ‘ scored a ‘ + i + ‘\n’

bestStudentStr = ‘\nThe Best Students Ranked\n\n’ + bestStudentStr

print(bestStudentStr)

outToFile = open(‘studentrank.txt’, mode=’w', encoding='utf-8′)
outToFile.write(bestStudentStr)

outToFile.close()

print(‘Finished update’)
```

Comment: SyntaxError:invalid syntax highlights the following line of code:(bestStudent[i]

Comment: You have some non-ASCII quotes `’` mixed in with ASCII quotes `'`. Change all of the non-ASCII to ASCII and you should be fine.

Comment: I also see a backtick `\`` in there. You will also need to change that to an ASCII quote.

Answer (score 0):

For the syntax error highlighting `bestStudent[i]` Replace that print statement with

`print (bestStudent[i] + 'scored a ' + i)`  with **()**

Also your code contains a lot of **‘ ’** instead of **' '** single-qoutes which you can simply replace

Fix those issues, I think it ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

Non-ascii characters replaced:

```
from __future__ import print_function

bestStudent = {}
f = open ("C:/Users/lenovo/workspace/assignment3/studentgrades.txt")
for line in f:
    name, grade = line.split()
    bestStudent[grade] = name

f.close()

bestStudentStr= "" 

for i in sorted(bestStudent.keys(), reverse=True):
    print bestStudent[i] + "scored a " + i
bestStudentStr += bestStudent[i] + " scored a " + i + "\n"

bestStudentStr = "\nThe Best Students Ranked\n\n" + bestStudentStr

print(bestStudentStr)

outToFile = open("studentrank.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8")
outToFile.write(bestStudentStr)

outToFile.close()

print("Finished update")
```

This happens when you copy source from pdf,doc etc file. The best solution is to copy/paste in a text editor without unicode support, you'll see then what wrong is as `?` marks.